# How to create a table with evently distributed column width, bullet point and automatic line breaks

Tags: tables, tabularx, bullets, textwidth, column-width

For my thesis, I need to create a table that look like this: [image]

The only thing I would like to be different, is that the bullet point are also horizontally aligned. Meaning that I want the second bullet point from each column to be at the same "height".

Unfortunately, I was until now not able to create a table that looks like the example.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, titlepage, a4paper, oneside, headsepline]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry} 

\begin{table}[htb]
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXX}

    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{broad} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{middle} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{narrow}\\
    \midrule
    \tabitem Control of strategic direction & \tabitem Founder or descendant runs the company & \tabitem Presence of multiple generations \\
    \tabitem Family participation & \tabitem Firm is intended to remain in the family & \tabitem More than one member of the owner's family with management responsibility \vspace{0.3cm}\\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\Downarrow$} \vspace{0.3cm} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\Downarrow$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\Downarrow$} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Little direct family involvement} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Some family involvement} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Strong family involvement} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

Using this code gives me:

[image]

However, I need the columns to be the same width. Also, I would like the text after the bullet points to be indented just like in the example picture.

Example: Instead of looking like this:
[image]

I would like the text to be indented like this:
[image]

I don't know what to try next and I am quite clueless. I really do appreciate your help!

Thank you so much,
Lea

Comment: Could you please make your code compilable? There are at least 2-3 packages missing. Also, how is `\tabitem` defined?

Comment: Could you please also clarify on the desired output? (Probably with a little sketch) You wrote "I want the second bullet point from each column to be at the same "height"" but as far as I can see from your second screenshot, this is already the case or a m I overlooking something?

Comment: Hi leandriis, sorry for my vague description and the missing packages. Also, you are correct and did not overlook anything. My second screenshot already fulfilled the "height requirement".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my suggestion. As already mentioned in the comments, the items are already vertically aligned. Therefore, my answer focuses on solving the second issue.

Since there was no definition of `\tabitem` given in the question and since you are not satisfied with the missing indentation of the second and following lines of the items, I have included an alternative `\tabitem` command based on the `enumitem` package. I have also used the `makecell` package in order to introduce linebreaks in the last row as teh contents in the first column  are too wide for the column width and cause an overfull box warning. I have also defined a new left aligned column type that derives from the `X` type columns. Lastly, I have added some `\addlinespace` commands to add some vertial white space between rowe.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, titlepage, a4paper, oneside, headsepline]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry} 

%\newcommand\tabitem{\makebox[1em][r]{\textbullet~}} % Probably your old definition of \tabitem?


\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{mytabitem}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[mytabitem]{nosep,leftmargin=*,before=\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip},after=\vspace{-1\baselineskip}, label=\textbullet}
\newcommand{\tabitem}[1]{\begin{mytabitem}\item #1\end{mytabitem}}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{YYY}

    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{broad} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{middle} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{narrow}\\
    \midrule
    \tabitem{Control of strategic direction} & \tabitem{Founder or descendant runs the company} & \tabitem{Presence of multiple generations} \\ \addlinespace
    \tabitem{Family participation} & \tabitem{Firm is intended to remain in the family} & \tabitem{More than one member of the owner's family with management responsibility} \vspace{0.3cm}\\ \addlinespace
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\Downarrow$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\Downarrow$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\Downarrow$} \\ \addlinespace
    \makecell{Little direct \\ family involvement} & \makecell{Some\\ family involvement} & \makecell{Strong\\ family involvement} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your suggested tabel fulfills all requirements I tried to describe in my initial question. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Your table is to wide, and you have to reduce left margin (or do other thing). I also removed the side bearing (`@{}`) of the columns to improve spacing. Since complicated code was no issue, I have streamlined the code by defining short-hands, but I focused on simple code to make it better understandable since you are new to LaTeX

In principle, what you do is to add an itemize environment into the second row's cells. Then you move the content of the third row's cells a new  second item of each itemize environment. I have loaded [enumitem](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem), because you then get full control over spacing.

The `\multicolumn{1}{c}{Text}` lines in last row cause problems, because they are wider than the text width and destroy the column calculation of [tabularx](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx). You either has to narrow the margin, reduce font size or convert the `c` to a `p{}`. Even with left margin `2cm` and removed side bearings, the heading *Little direct family involvement* is slightly wider that 1/3 textwidth (you see this if you look close). If possible, you can remove the word "direct", reduce font size to `\small` or set the left and right margins to 1.9 cm.

Here is a MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, titlepage, a4paper, oneside, headsepline]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[left=1.9cm,right=1.9cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx, enumitem, array}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\@minipagetrue\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, nosep]}X<{\end{itemize}}} 
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\centering

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}*{3}{Y}@{}}
\toprule
\mc{\itshape Broad} & \mc{\itshape Middle} & \mc{\itshape Narrow}\\
\midrule
    \item      Control of strategic direction 
    \item      Family participation
&
    \item      Founder or descendant runs the company 
    \item      Firm is intended to remain in the family 
&
    \item      Presence of multiple generations
    \item      More than one member of the owner's family with management responsibility 
\\
\addlinespace[0.3cm]
\mc{$\Downarrow$} &
\mc{$\Downarrow$} &
\mc{$\Downarrow$} \\
\addlinespace[0.3cm]
\mc{Little direct family involvement} &
\mc{Some family involvement}           &
\mc{Strong family involvement}         \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```